# Passing a struct* from one Cython class to another

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to pass a struct pointer from one Cython class to another. Here is some example code:

```
cdef struct MyStruct:
    int a
    int b

cdef class MyClass:
    cdef MyStruct* s
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = <MyStruct*> malloc(sizeof(MyStruct))
        self.s.a = 1
        self.s.b = 2

    cdef MyStruct* get_my_struct(self):
        return self.s

cdef class PrinterClass:
    cdef object m
    def __init__(self):
        self.m = MyClass()

    cpdef print_struct(self):
        cdef MyStruct* my_struct
        my_struct = self.m.get_my_struct()
        print(my_struct.a)
```

When I try to compile this class, I get these 2 errors around the `my_struct = self.m.get_my_struct()` line:

> Cannot convert Python object to 'MyStruct *

and

> Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference

Why is Cython attempting to do conversions here? Can't it just pass the pointer as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `PrinterClass`, replace `cdef object m` with `cdef MyClass m` or explicitly cast `self.m` to `MyClass`: `my_struct = (<MyClass>self.m).get_my_struct()`. (In addition, a `__dealloc__` should be added to `MyClass`).

I guess the difference lies in that `object` is a python object(in essence,`dict`), while `cdef class` is another kind of class(in essence, `struct`), see [Extension types (aka. cdef classes)](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html#extension-types-aka-cdef-classes).

Expect further revelations from other experts :)